# Use firehose to consume data from Kinesis stream, report Kinesis Throttling error

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

message:
Throttling error encountered when calling Kinesis. This can be due to other applications calling the same APIs as the Firehose delivery stream, or because you have created too many Firehose delivery streams with the same Kinesis stream as the source.

How to solve this error？

Thanks

Comment: How do you "call" Kinesis? Are you using KCL?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am reading Kinesis from Firehose delivery stream. I only have this one Firehose reading from it. Also, there is no other API reading from the same stream. What is the way to investigate this?